# Print contents of a hidden div

Tags: html, printing

On my page I have a HTML DIV that is shown on the screen and another hidden. I carry this hidden DIV content of a report I need to print, I need to click on it so that the user can not see it, only in print. Further, the contents of the DIV that is shown on screen, I do not want to come out in print. ;)

've Researched enough here in stackoverflow some topics that talk about it but it is talking about the opposite, ie not print the contents of the hidden DIV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply toggle visibility when sending to print.

```
Example HTML:

<div id="printdiv">
    <div id="hidden_div">
        MORE HTML
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hidden_div{display: none;}
```

**JQuery**

```
function myPrint() {
        var myPrintContent = document.getElementById('printdiv');
        var myPrintWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=300,top=100,width=400,height=400');
        myPrintWindow.document.write(myPrintContent.innerHTML);
        myPrintWindow.document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display='block'
        myPrintWindow.document.close();
        myPrintWindow.focus();
        myPrintWindow.print();
        myPrintWindow.close();    
        return false;
    }
```

Now use a button or link to fire `myPrint()` and you can print that hidden div alone and your other div won't be printed

Comment: In this case how would the css?

Comment: it's there: you have a #hidden_div:display:none" that is changed to block when printed

Comment: Careful with this method - many browsers will block the window.open command.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to do that without needing Javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .a {color: green;}
            .b {color: blue;}
            .printMe {display: none;}
            @media print {
                div {display: none;}
                .printMe {display: block;}
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="a">Some text.</div>
        <div class="printMe">Only to be shown in print.</div>
        <div class="b">More characters.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I have formatted the CSS like that only for brevity.)

If you load that into a browser, you should see only the coloured text. If you do a print preview, you should see only the black text.

**Edit:** You can still use whatever other method you desire to do the printing, be it through simple Javascript or the user using the browser's print method.

Comment: Very good and simple this way, better yet you do not need to use JS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look in to the `@print` stylesheet option.

[See this article here too:](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)

Comment: I think you meant `@media print`, and a better article to link to would have been one contained in the article you linked to: [Print stylesheet - the definitive guide](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml). As it is, you need to provide an answer which is full enough to stand on its own (as far as possible) without referring to outside resources which might disappear in the future.